# Get previous fragment back

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

Here is my code snippet:
I want to create a new fragment initially, but if the fragment is already created the i want to show the previous fragment;

But every time a new fragment is initialise.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     .
     .
    showFragment(FRAGMENT_ADD_DETAILS);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            if(currentFragment==FRAGMENT_ADD_DETAILS){
                finish();
            }else{
                showFragment(FRAGMENT_ADD_DETAILS);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.menu_action_next:
            showFragment(FRAGMENT_INVITE_FRIENDS);
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     .
     .
    return true;
}


private void showFragment(int fragmentType) {
    Log.d(TAG,"showFragment : "+fragmentType);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    Fragment prevFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(String.valueOf(fragmentType));
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    if (prevFragment == null) { //create a fresh instance of fragment
        Log.d(TAG,"Initialize new fragment");
        Fragment newFragment;
        if (fragmentType == FRAGMENT_ADD_DETAILS) {
            newFragment = new NewDetailsFragment();
        } else {
            newFragment = new NewInviteFragment();
        }
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.ant_container_layout, newFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(String.valueOf(fragmentType));
    } else {//just reuse the previous fragment
        Log.d(TAG,"Re-Using previous fragment");
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.ant_container_layout, prevFragment);
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 2):

You never add any tags to your fragments, so you cannot find them by using `findFragmentByTag()`.

When you replace a fragment, instead of

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.ant_container_layout, newFragment);
```

use the overloaded method that accepts a tag:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.ant_container_layout, newFragment, String.valueOf(fragmentType));
```

---

You try to restore your fragments in `onCreate()` of your activity but it seems that you haven't retained your fragments. They are thus destroyed together with the activity and when the activity is created again, new fragments are created.

Comment: Maybe you need to post more code... But you definitely need to add tags as you won't be able to find anything by tag.

Comment: From what you posted, it's hard to say whether fragments are still there or not when you call this method. Where do you call it from?

Comment: See my update. It's probably too hard for me to say what you exactly need to do as it depends on your exact needs. Read a bit more about fragment's lifecycle, detaching/attaching fragments, etc.